# Successive states with only one change without repetition of previous state

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to build a piece of code that generates successive lists of ints which can take only two states: 0 or 1.
The contraint are the following:

- the state t+1 cannot be the same as state t
- the duo (t, t+1) cannot be retrieved
- bonus: all combinations of two successive changes are generated

Here is an example:
Let assume that I have at T0 a list with four ints: [0, 1, 1, 0]
The next state T1 CANNOT be [0, 1, 1, 0].
The next state T1 can be either:

- [1, 1, 1, 0]
- [0, 0, 1, 0]
- [0, 1, 0, 0]
- [0, 1, 1, 1]

The state T2 can be equals to whatever.
If T2 was equal to T0, the state T3 CANNOT be equals to what was in T1 in order to have a sequence different between (T0, T1) and (T2, T3).

I try to solve this problem from days, but cannot figure out how to. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you want a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)?

Comment: Actually, any mapping of integers to binary representations of the integers would probably suffice.

Comment: Damn ! Never knew about grey code or binary representation of integer, but I searched for it and it seems to make the job. Thank you very much sir !